# How to simulate neutron detector under geant4 under python?

Tags: python, geant4

Under python , i want to develop :

- A detector CSL ( TI) with geometry of 1 cm * 1 cm * 2 cm
- will detect shielded container of cobalt ( 60 ) with a cylinder
  geometry.

> ```
> import geant4_pybind as g4
> import os
>
> # Set the G4ENSDFSTATEDATA environment variable
> ensdfstate_data_path = r"C:\Users\mouad\Desktop\G4\gears\INSTALL\Geant4\data\G4ENSDFSTATE2.3"
> os.environ["G4ENSDFSTATEDATA"] = ensdfstate_data_path
>
> # Initialize NIST Material Manager
> nist_manager = g4.G4NistManager.Instance()
>
> # Materials
> air = nist_manager.FindOrBuildMaterial("G4_AIR")
> silicon = nist_manager.FindOrBuildMaterial("G4_Si")
> lead = nist_manager.FindOrBuildMaterial("G4_Pb")
>
> # World Volume
> world_size = 1 * g4.m
> world_solid = g4.G4Box("World", world_size/2, world_size/2, world_size/2)
> world_logic = g4.G4LogicalVolume(world_solid, air, "World")
> world_phys = g4.G4PVPlacement(g4.G4Transform3D(), world_logic, "World", None, False, 0)
>
> # Detector Volume
> detector_size = g4.G4ThreeVector(1 * g4.cm, 1 * g4.cm, 2 * g4.cm)
> detector_solid = g4.G4Box("Detector", detector_size.x/2, detector_size.y/2, detector_size.z/2)
> detector_logic = g4.G4LogicalVolume(detector_solid, silicon, "Detector")
> detector_position = g4.G4ThreeVector(0, 0, 0)
> detector_phys = g4.G4PVPlacement(g4.G4Transform3D(), detector_logic, "Detector", world_logic, False, 0)
>
> # Source Container (Cylindrical Geometry)
> container_radius = 5 * g4.cm
> container_height = 10 * g4.cm
> container_solid = g4.G4Tubs("Container", 0, container_radius, container_height/2, 0, 2*g4.pi)
> container_logic = g4.G4LogicalVolume(container_solid, lead, "Container")
> container_position = g4.G4ThreeVector(0, 0, 5 * g4.cm)
> container_phys = g4.G4PVPlacement(g4.G4Transform3D(), container_logic, "Container", world_logic, False, 0)
>
> # Create a run manager
> run_manager = g4.G4RunManager()
>
> # Physics List
> physics_list = g4.FTFP_BERT()
> run_manager.SetUserInitialization(physics_list)
>
> # Initialize and Run
> run_manager.Initialize()
> run_manager.BeamOn(1000)  # Number of events to simulate
> ```

I got following error :

```
>>> run_manager = g4.G4RunManager()

-------- EEEE ------- G4Exception-START -------- EEEE -------
    *** G4Exception : PART70001
          issued by : G4NuclideTable
    ENSDFSTATE.dat is not found.
    *** Fatal Exception *** core dump ***
     **** Track information is not available at this moment
     **** Step information is not available at this moment
    
    -------- EEEE -------- G4Exception-END --------- EEEE -------
    
    
    *** G4Exception: Aborting execution ***
```

Comment: Not familiar with this package, but your error states `ENSDFSTATE.dat is not found.` so possibly your file path may have a typo at the top of your code? Also states that G4NuclideTable issued the error,    so it may be one of the materials has an issue?